What is the Biblical Basis for Replacement Theology, the shifting of the birthright from Israel to the Church?
I'm new to the website, but found the discussion of birthright to be edifying and certainly consistent with church history.  In relation to @pehkay's statement, "Furthermore, in the New Testament the birthright is shifted from Israel to the church" in that discussion, my question is this:  Is the shifting of the birthright from Israel to the Church, of God or of man, and how does Scripture support your answer?

Is there a question？Please state clearly!

what discussion on birthright?

Hi Noel, welcome to the site. The question is ... well lacking a concrete question. A general overview would be a response, but that isn't clear that you are seeking that. Try to state things in your questions (and answers) more explicitly. It is not obvious what you are asking, even if you think it is.

@ Noel - The question seems to be Was the shifting of Israel's birthright to the Church real, thereby justifying the "Replacement Theory"? And if so, which scriptures state this? (prove this?)---Is this your meaning of the question? If so, it can then be objectively answered on S.E.

Hello Noel. The Ethnic Israel of the OT was a picture of the spiritual Israel. Just like the physical circumcision, the sacrifices and the temple were. On top of that, ekklésia does not mean "the church". The word is used 77 times in the Greek OT (Septuagint) and always described the assembly of the ethnic Israel. Which were the physical descendants of Jacob with the mixed multitude that joined them during the exodus and after.

https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/inflections.cfm?strongs=G1577&t=lxx&ot=LXX&word=%E1%BC%90%CE%BA%CE%BA%CE%BB%CE%B7%CF%83%E1%BD%B7%CE%B1

I go into more details in my answers to those questions:

https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/94044/deeper-understanding-as-to-why-isaiah-493s-reference-to-my-servant-israel-f/94062#94062

https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/88343/riddle-how-is-a-jew-not-a-jew-but-a-gentile-is-a-jew/88369#88369

It is a little imprecise, but not really wrong, to say that Israel's birthright has shifted to the Church. The birthright has been inherited by the Christians and is no longer held by the ethno-religious Jews of the present era. The birthright was inherited by Jesus and passes to the Church through him. It's not so much that the birthright shifted to the Church as that the Church is included into covenantal Israel, while Jews who reject Jesus are excluded.
This idea found primarily in Galatians and Ephesians, but it also draws on many other parts of Scripture, especially Hebrews and Romans.
I should mention before going into details that what is often called "replacement theology" by its opponents is more properly called supercessionism. This is the belief that the New Covenant in Christ supersedes the old, Mosaic Covenant. The Old Covenant is now obsolete (Hebrews 8:13). The people of the New Covenant are the Church, which includes both ethnic Jews and Gentiles who believe in the Messiah and receive the signs of the new covenant. Thus, the Jews are not replaced but rather included into the new community, as long as they do not reject Jesus (c.f. Romans 9:6-8, 11:1). Far from being replaced, Jewish followers of Jesus form the very foundation of the Church, as all the Apostles were Jewish, as were most of their disciples.
Transferring the Birthright in Galatians
The promise of God was first given to Abraham, then inherited by Isaac (Gen. 26), and then transferred according to the birthright to Jacob, a.k.a. Israel (this transferal being expressly ratified by God in Gen. 35:11-12). Israel's descendants collectively carried the promise until the time of Christ.
Galatians 3 has a lot to say about this, but the crux of the issue is in verse 16:

Now the promises were made to Abraham and to his offspring. It does not say, “And to offsprings,” referring to many, but referring to one, “And to your offspring,” who is Christ. (ESV)

Thus Christ himself is the fulfillment of the promise to Abraham. We read at the end of the chapter:

for in Christ Jesus you are all sons of God, through faith. For as many of you as were baptized into Christ have put on Christ. There is neither Jew nor Greek, there is neither slave nor free, there is no male and female, for you are all one in Christ Jesus. And if you are Christ's, then you are Abraham's offspring, heirs according to promise.

It is true that the distinctions of slave vs. free, male vs. female, and Jew vs. Greek are not absolutely nullified here, as dispensationalists correctly point out. But verse 29 is eminently clear: These distinctions are nullified as regards the promise of God to Abraham, which was the same promise inherited by Isaac and Israel. This works because we are all included in Christ Jesus, who is the offspring of Abraham.
Galatians 4 goes on to call the Church children of the Jerusalem above, and 6:16 calls the faithful "Israel of God". These reiterate the point that the Church inherits the OT identity of "Israel", regardless of ethnicity. (And it should be noted that even in the OT, people of foreign birth were able to join themselves to Israel and enter into the covenant community, see Exodus 12:48-49, Ruth 1:16, and Joshua 8:33-35.)
Unification of Jew and Gentile in Ephesians
Ephesians 2:11-3:13 has a similar message:

2:11 Therefore remember that at one time you Gentiles in the flesh, called “the uncircumcision” by what is called the circumcision, which is made in the flesh by hands— 12 remember that you were at that time separated from Christ, alienated from the commonwealth of Israel and strangers to the covenants of promise, having no hope and without God in the world. 13 But now in Christ Jesus you who once were far off have been brought near by the blood of Christ. 14 For he himself is our peace, who has made us both one and has broken down in his flesh the dividing wall of hostility 15 by abolishing the law of commandments expressed in ordinances, that he might create in himself one new man in place of the two, so making peace, 16 and might reconcile us both to God in one body through the cross, thereby killing the hostility. 17 And he came and preached peace to you who were far off and peace to those who were near. 18 For through him we both have access in one Spirit to the Father. 19 So then you are no longer strangers and aliens, but you are fellow citizens with the saints and members of the household of God, 20 built on the foundation of the apostles and prophets, Christ Jesus himself being the cornerstone, 21 in whom the whole structure, being joined together, grows into a holy temple in the Lord. 22 In him you also are being built together into a dwelling place for God by the Spirit.


3:1 For this reason I, Paul, a prisoner of Christ Jesus on behalf of you Gentiles— 2 assuming that you have heard of the stewardship of God's grace that was given to me for you, 3 how the mystery was made known to me by revelation, as I have written briefly. 4 When you read this, you can perceive my insight into the mystery of Christ, 5 which was not made known to the sons of men in other generations as it has now been revealed to his holy apostles and prophets by the Spirit. 6 This mystery is that the Gentiles are fellow heirs, members of the same body, and partakers of the promise in Christ Jesus through the gospel.


7 Of this gospel I was made a minister according to the gift of God's grace, which was given me by the working of his power. 8 To me, though I am the very least of all the saints, this grace was given, to preach to the Gentiles the unsearchable riches of Christ, 9 and to bring to light for everyone what is the plan of the mystery hidden for ages in God, who created all things, 10 so that through the church the manifold wisdom of God might now be made known to the rulers and authorities in the heavenly places. 11 This was according to the eternal purpose that he has realized in Christ Jesus our Lord, 12 in whom we have boldness and access with confidence through our faith in him. 13 So I ask you not to lose heart over what I am suffering for you, which is your glory.

The clear and overall force of these verses is that, because of what Christ has done, the difference between Jew and Gentile has been overcome. There is no longer a division among the faithful.
Some details to note: The "fellow citizens" of 2:19, when taken in context of v.12, must mean citizens of Israel. There is also a parallel of 2:12 and 3:6:

Remember that you were at that time separated from Christ, alienated from the commonwealth of Israel and strangers to the covenants of promise, having no hope and without God in the world.


This mystery is that the Gentiles are fellow heirs, members of the same body, and partakers of the promise in Christ Jesus through the gospel.

The Greek of 3:6 is highly anaphoric and hard to translate, more literally it might read "co-heirs, co-body-members, and co-partakers of the promise". Thus, we have that threefold separation of 2:12 finds a threefold unification in 3:6.
Prophecy
For the reasons mentioned above, the New Testament authors applied OT prophecy about Israel to the Church in 1st Peter 2:25, Romans 9:25-26, 2nd Cor.6:2,6:16-18, and Hebrews 8. This works because the Church is, as regards the covenants, the same as the OT covenant Israel. Some other prophecies in the Old Testament hint at a future inclusion of the nations into Israel, see in particular Psalm 87, Zechariah 2:11, Ezekiel 47:22-23, Isaiah 14:1, and Isaiah 56:3-8. For this reason, it is no surprise that early church writers (such as Clement of Rome and Irenaeus and too many others to mention) took OT prophecy about Israel and applied it to the Church. They were simply following the example of Scripture itself.
Details pointing toward supercessionism
Throughout the New Testament, Jesus and the Apostles use language clearly mirroring OT "Israelish" terminology, but apply it to Christians (Luke 3:8, 1st Peter 1:1, 2:9, 2:11-12, 3:6, 4:3, James 1:1, Col. 2:11, Phil. 3:3, 1st Corinthians 10:1). At the same time, Jesus regards unfaithful Jews, i.e. those that reject him, as not being genuine Jews at all in John 8:39-40 and Rev. 3:9.
In Romans 11:11-24, Paul makes an analogy of the olive tree representing the true people of God. Gentile believers are branches grafted on, while Jewish believers the natural branches. But those Jews who reject Jesus are cut off an no longer part of the olive tree.
Similarly, John 10:16 indicates inclusion of Gentiles into "one flock" with the Jews, while John 10:26 shows that the Jews who do not believe in Jesus are not part of this flock.
Conclusion
The Bible teaches that ethnic Gentiles who believe in Jesus, the Jewish Messiah and the promised seed of Abraham, are included into the covenant community of Israel (in continuity with the OT saints who looked forward to the coming of Christ, c.f. Hebrews 11), while those ethnic Jews who reject Jesus are excluded from that covenant. The Church, meaning the people of the New Covenant irrespective of ethnicity, is the true inheritor of Israel's birthright, as we are in Christ Jesus in whom all the covenants are fulfilled.

"These reiterate the point that the Church inherits the OT identity of "Israel", regardless of ethnicity.". Believing Israel is the one olive tree and believing Gentiles are grafted into them.  We must be careful not to make it seem the other way around.  Overall, good answer. +1

@ Mike Borden - The  analogy of the Olive tree, written to Roman Jews, is just one metaphor to encourage the Jewish believers. The other illustrations in the New Testament, rely heavily on the fact that the Promises of universal redemption were given to Abraham while he was a Gentile! (uncircumcised)  So "Jew and Gentile" distinction is feckless.  BUT THE HISTORY of the Jews does provide symbolism that helps us understand "covenant relationship with God",  the meaning of "sin sacrifice, and " Kingdom of Christ."  God so loves the world and the Israelites were a schoolmaster to teach us that.

@raygrant I cannot agree that Romans was written to Roman Jews because in the very same passage Paul exhorts the Gentiles ( his audience) not to boast about their being grafted in.  He repeatedly uses they (the Jews) and you (Gentiles) throughout the passage.

@raygrant "For I speak to you Gentiles, inasmuch as I am the apostle of the Gentiles, I magnify mine office: " - Romans 11:13

Truly fab answer, +1

Not disputing the scholarly and well thought-out responses here, I'll answer my own question in the Hebrew fashion seen throughout Scripture: asking rhetorical questions.  So, as we survey the ~1400 years BC plus the ~2000 years AD wherein God's covenant with Israel/Judah was carried out exactly as specified in Deuteronomy 27-28, what makes you believe that our Lord, who is the same yesterday, today, and forever (Hebrews 13:8) and through whom all that is was created (John 1:3), suddenly changed His mind at the 1400-year mark and rescinded His covenant with the Jews?  Has it not been served upon Israel and Judah -- the blessings and the curses -- throughout all this time?  Yes, the Jews have broken that covenant again and again, but what makes you believe, against all evidence, that it's no longer in force?  In what way are the sufferings of the Jewish people not part of the covenant agreement?  Is a broken covenant really a rescinded one?  Would it make sense to suppose that after all the pain and suffering of invasion, exile, re-gathering, and so on, God would suddenly change the program and announce to His people, "From now on, don't keep the commandments of the Torah," and then punish them when when they did?  And speaking of re-gathering, how is the in-gathering that's been taking place since WW1 and Israel's current status as "the fruit basket of Europe" not evidence of His continued covenant?  (Think of Psalm 95:7 -- "He is our God, and we are the people of His pasture and the sheep of His hand. Today, if you would hear His voice.")

2000 years consistently without a temple, an altar, or the access to atonement therein coupled with the Christian's 2000 years of claiming that those things are fulfilled in Christ?  There's a lot of weight there.

God did not nor does he punish people for keeping the commands of the Torah. The Jews broke the covenant by rejecting Jesus. The New Covenant is offered to any Jews who accept him.

You may well be right that the sufferings of the Jewish people are God's judgment against them from the Mosaic Covenant. That's an old and respectable biblical interpretation, which I do lean towards but I do not see it so evidently manifest in Scripture as many other things I believe. In that case, then we ought to look forward to God's restoration of the Jews which will mean their conversion to Christianity. That's a natural interpretation of Romans 11 and was also believed by Augustine and other church fathers

Hi, Dark.  The wording of the blessings and curses which the first generation post-Egypt sang to each other from Mt. Gerizim and Mt. Ebal as per Moses' instructions given in what we call Deut 27 (Messianic Jews call it Ki Tavo -- Hebrew for "When you enter...") are quite specific.  Paul was very clear about the Torah not being nullified (Romans 3:31) and he was only emphasizing what Yeshua had spoken about jots and tittles in Matthew 5:18.  The cool part of history is the huge surge of faith in Messiah throughout Israel over the past quarter-century.

Are you disagreeing with something that I've said?

Could you format it a little so it is easier to read?
